# Python Flask app is not running on Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm trying to run the Flask app on my Apache server in the subfolder.

I have this setup:

I added the Alias "sendbase" to my primary domain, which led to the folder that has wsgi file and backend.

```
000-default-le-ssl.conf 

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName octanehq.org
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        Alias /sendbase /var/www/sendbase

        WSGIDaemonProcess sendbase threads=5 python-home=/var/www/sendbase/env python-path=/var/www/sendbase
        WSGIScriptAlias /sendbase /var/www/sendbase/sendbase1.wsgi
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        <Directory /var/www/sendbase/backend>
           WSGIProcessGroup sendbase
           WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
           Require all granted
           Options -Indexes
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/octanehq.org-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/octanehq.org-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

sendbase.wsgi 

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'WSGI script is working!'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]


#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/sendbase")

from test import app as application
application.secret_key = 'secretkey'  # Replace with your actual secret key
```

for some reason, the python is not working. If I place the index.html in the folder, it works. I have another Python app on the subdomain and it works fine. Not sure what I'm doing wrong with this one.

I did the Apache setup to run the Flask Python app according to the instructions, but it is not working in the browser. Not sure how to debug.